# axios get request infinitely looping

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, request

In my function `getFact()`, I make a GET and return the data. The issue that I'm having is that the request is looping infinitely instead of just once.

here's my code:

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function Facts() {

  const [fact, setFact] = useState("");
  const [source, setSource] = useState("");
  const [id, setID] = useState("");

  function getFact() {
    axios.get("https://exampleAPI.com/",  { crossdomain: true }).then(response => {
      setFact(response.data[0].fact);
      setSource(response.data[0].sources);
      setID(response.data[0].id);
    });
  }

  getFact();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 class="text-light fw-light landing-text">{id}</h1>
      <p class="text-light">fact number</p>
      <hr class="text-light" />
      <h1 class="text-light fw-light landing-text">"{fact}"</h1>
      <a class="text-light text-decoration-none" href={source} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">source</a>
      <br />
      <br />
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-light" onClick={getFact}>
          Next Fact
      </button>
    </div>    
  )
}

export default Facts;
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You're calling getFact on click event. Why do you also call it above the return statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what it appears, you want to run `getFact` when the component mounts i.e. once for a component's lifecycle.
To accomplish it, use `useEffect` hook with empty dependency array.

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function Facts() {

  const [fact, setFact] = useState("");
  const [source, setSource] = useState("");
  const [id, setID] = useState("");

  function getFact() {
    axios.get("https://exampleAPI.com/",  { crossdomain: true }).then(response => {
      setFact(response.data[0].fact);
      setSource(response.data[0].sources);
      setID(response.data[0].id);
    });
  }

  // call getFact in a useEffect hook
  useEffect(() => {
    getFact();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 class="text-light fw-light landing-text">{id}</h1>
      <p class="text-light">fact number</p>
      <hr class="text-light" />
      <h1 class="text-light fw-light landing-text">"{fact}"</h1>
      <a class="text-light text-decoration-none" href={source} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">source</a>
      <br />
      <br />
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-light" onClick={getFact}>
          Next Fact
      </button>
    </div>    
  )
}

export default Facts;
```

In your code, you're calling `getFact` function directly in the body of `Facts` functional component which means getFact will be called on every render. Also, you're updating the state (`setFact`) in the getFact function and hence making the component re-render whenever getFact is called. This creates an infinite loop.

In the above solution, getFact function will only be called when component is mounted.

You can benefit from these resources:

- [useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)
- [Component lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `useEffect` hook to handle the API call. The reason why is calls infinitely is because you call `getFact` every time the component is rendered, and within `getFact` you making a state update. Every time the state is updated the component is re-rendered, which then call `getFact` again, causing the infinite loop.

Try something like this:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function Facts() {

  const [fact, setFact] = useState("");
  const [source, setSource] = useState("");
  const [id, setID] = useState("");
  
  function getFact() {
    axios.get("https://exampleAPI.com/",  { crossdomain: true }).then(response => {
      setFact(response.data[0].fact);
      setSource(response.data[0].sources);
      setID(response.data[0].id);
    });
  };

  useEffect(()=>{
    getFact();
  },[]);


  return (
    <div>
      <h1 class="text-light fw-light landing-text">{id}</h1>
      <p class="text-light">fact number</p>
      <hr class="text-light" />
      <h1 class="text-light fw-light landing-text">"{fact}"</h1>
      <a class="text-light text-decoration-none" href={source} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">source</a>
      <br />
      <br />
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-light" onClick={getFact}>
          Next Fact
      </button>
    </div>    
  )
}

export default Facts;
```

Notice how I called `getFact` within `useEffect`. It'll call `getFact` only when the component is first rendered. `useEffect` also accepts a list of dependencies, which will determine if what ever is specified within the function will run. But I passed an empty array as my dependencies. See [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), for more information.